# mvvmcross Viewmodel.Initialize is fired before you can hook InitializeTask.PropertyChanged

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

In my app, I want to know in the View when Initialize is complete.  The problem is that it gets launched before you can hook  InitializeTask.PropertyChanged.  Here is my ViewModel code:

```
    public override async Task Initialize()
    {
        ClientID = await MyDataSource.GetClientID();

    }
```

In my View I am doing the following:

```
    protected override void OnViewModelSet()
    {
        var vm = this.DataContext as MyViewModel;

        vm.InitializeTask.PropertyChanged += InitializeTask_PropertyChanged;

        base.OnViewModelSet();
    }

    private void InitializeTask_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "IsSuccessfullyCompleted")
        {
            vm.InitializeTask.PropertyChanged -= InitializeTask_PropertyChanged;
            if (vm.ClientID != "")
                posClient = new PosClient(this, vm.ClientID);
        }
    }
```

As far as I know, OnViewModelSet is the soonest that you have access to your ViewModel in your View.  If I put in breakpoints, Initialize runs before OnViewModelSet is fired.  This makes it very likely that Initialize has finished before you can hook the event.  Is there another place in the View where you can hook the event before Initialize starts so you will be guaranteed to Initialize.PropertyChanged will fire in the View?

**** Update ****

I followed @fmaccaroni advice and implemented an MvxInteraction called DataLoaded.  One thing I did different was to create a separate function to load the data.

```
    public void LoadData()
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            ClientID = await IHSDataSource.GetClientID();
            _DataLoaded.Raise();
        });
    }
```

I was concerned about the async task finishing before I got the interaction event wired up.  Doing it this way, I added this in the View.

```
    protected override void OnViewModelSet()
    {
        vm = this.DataContext as InvoiceViewModel;

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<InvoiceView, InvoiceViewModel>();
        set.Bind(this).For(view => view.DataLoaded).To(viewModel => viewModel.DataLoaded).OneWay();
        set.Apply();

        vm.LoadData();

        base.OnViewModelSet();
    }
```

This way, LoadData does not start until I am sure the result will trigger the interaction and I am guaranteed to get the result.  This was the first I had heard about MvxInteraction and I am now using it all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but if you want to take an action in your view when the `Initialize` ends just do an [MvxInteraction](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/mvxinteraction) and call it after your `await`, i.e.:

ViewModel:

```
private MvxInteraction _interaction = new MvxInteraction();
public IMvxInteraction MyMvxInteraction => _interaction;

public override async Task Initialize()
{
    ClientID = await MyDataSource.GetClientID();
    this._interaction.Raise();
}
```

View:

```
private IMvxInteraction _interaction;
public IMvxInteraction MyMvxInteraction
{
    get => this._interaction;
    set
    {
        if (this._interaction != null)
            this._interaction.Requested -= this.OnInteractionRequested;

        this._interaction = value;
        this._interaction.Requested += this.OnInteractionRequested;
    }
}

private void OnInteractionRequested(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var vm = this.DataContext as MyViewModel;

    if (vm.ClientID != "")
        posClient = new PosClient(this, vm.ClientID);
}
```

and the binding in the view:

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MyView, MyViewModel>();
set.Bind(this).For(view => view.MyMvxInteraction).To(viewModel => viewModel.MyMvxInteraction).OneWay();
set.Apply();
```

Comment: Where would I put the binding?  In the OnCreate?

Comment: Even this method you would need it wired up before Initialize is fired.  Maybe put the binding in the constructor for the View?

Comment: in activities, in the OnCreate and in fragments OnCreateView

Comment: Can you put it before the base.OnCreate?  It seems that it would not be wired up in time since (I think) the base.OnCreate is where Initialize is fired.